# How to resize "ImageMesh"

Tags: graphics, mesh

How to make high resolution `DiscretizeRegion` from the given image?

[image]

```
ImageDimensions[img]
```

> $\{963, 594\}$

For instance there is a small size (about $10 \times 10$) but high resolution mesh region of Germany

```
Show[DiscretizeRegion[
Entity["Country", "Germany"]["Polygon"] /. GeoPosition -> Identity],
Graphics[Disk[{35, 10}, 5]]]
```

[image]

I want to make small size and high resolution  mesh region from the given `img`

```
Show[img // ImageMesh // DiscretizeRegion, Graphics[Disk[{40, 10}, 5]]]
```

[image]

Comment: could you provide an example image with which to work with?

Comment: @glS this is original [image](http://imgur.com/Fp9QQT7),  then use `ChanVeseBinarize`  for mask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option `DataRange`, from the [relevant documentation page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageMesh.html), does what you want:

[image]

Mind that the aspect ratio is not preserved in this way, so you have to manually use the correct values for x- and y-range to preserve the original one.

A way to automatically extract the aspect ratio of the original image is using `ImageDimensions`:

```
originalAspectRatio = #[[2]]/#[[1]] &@ImageDimensions@img;
With[{newSize = 40},
 Show[
  ImageMesh[img, 
   DataRange -> {{0, #}, {0, originalAspectRatio #}} &@newSize],
  Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Wrapping it all up in a function:

```
meshDiscretizeAndResize[img_Image, newSize_Integer] := With[{
   originalAspectRatio = #[[2]]/#[[1]] &@ImageDimensions@img
   },
  DiscretizeRegion@ImageMesh[img,
    DataRange -> {{0, #}, {0, originalAspectRatio #}} &@newSize
    ]
  ]
```

An example showing it work as intended:

[image]