# ImageMesh precision

Tags: graphics, mesh, conversion

Browsing though the documentation of `ImageMesh` I found it lacking with regard to its methods and options concerning mesh generation. In my application I have an image with very fine details (compared to the size of the image as a whole) as a `Graphics` object. How does one increase the precision used to generate the mesh?

Answer (score 4):

`ImageMesh` is designed to work with binary `Image`s only, hence it automatically rasterizes `Graphics` objects by applying `Image` and `Binarize` to them:

```
Trace[ImageMesh@Graphics[{Black, Disk[], White, RegularPolygon[1, 5]}],
 Image[_Graphics] | _Binarize]
```

> [image: output]

Due to the above reason, you should compare the obtained mesh not with `Graphics`, but with the result of rasterization:

```
Grid[Partition[Table[Framed@Grid[{{s, SpanFromLeft},
        {Image[Binarize@#, ImageSize -> 100],
         ImageMesh[#, Method -> "MarchingSquares", ImageSize -> 100]}}] &@
    Graphics[{Black, Disk[], White, RegularPolygon[1, 5]}, 
     ImageSize -> s], {s, 20, 80, 5}], 3]]
```

> [image: grid]

By the way, the Documentation statement

> `ImageMesh` works with arbitrary 2D and 3D images, taking the nonzero pixels of the image as foreground.

isn't quite correct as you can see from the above `Trace` output: actually for 2D images the binarization is performed using Otsu's algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Even though `Graphics` are not exactly pixel images but rather more like vector images, setting `ImageSize` does have an effect on the mesh quality.

Take for instance

```
Manipulate[
Region[#, PlotLabel -> s] &@
ImageMesh[#, Method -> "MarchingSquares"] &@
Graphics[{Black, Disk[], White, RegularPolygon[1, 5]}, 
ImageSize -> s], {s, 20, 300, 1}]
```

[image: manipulate]

I'd personally prefer there to be an explicit method option for `ImageMesh`, e.g. "MeshPrecision" for use with `Graphics`; this does work for my application just fine though.

Comment: See also [this Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140014/how-to-resize-imagemesh)